# Printing div works but has whitespace at top jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok i'm building an invoice application and i'm trying to print out a div that contains the invoice. I had the idea to hide all the div's except the div which contains the invoice content and then print that div.

**Like this:**

```
  // on click of print button hide all div's except invoice and then force print
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click', '.print_button', function() {
        $('.print_invoice').css({width: '100%'}, {height: "100%"});
        $('.hide_this').hide();
        window.print();

        // return all hidden div's on invoice click
        $('.print_invoice').click(function() {
          $('.hide_this').show();
          $(this).css({width: '83.33333333%'},{height: '60%'});
        });
      });
    });
```

And it works fine except that it has a big whitespace at the top when printing and because of that it forces parts of the footer to a second page.

**Like this:**

[image]

**How can i remove that big white space at the top and push the invoice up so it fits in one page?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a dedicated CSS stylesheet for print:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

There you can do a bit of reset.

*Rememeber*: disable the print headers option when printing, it helps.